# I am trying to get my facebook data in R using Rfacebook package

Tags: r, facebook

I am trying to get my facebook data in R using Rfacebook package. When I am trying to run getUsers API I am get below error:

me <- getUsers("me", token=fb_oauth, private_info=FALSE)
Error in callAPI(query, token) : 
  (#12) username is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher

Can someone suggest what should I use in place of "me"

Comment: Maybe try [this method](http://www.relevanceweb.com/blog/item/how-to-find-your-facebook-userid) to get your user ID

Comment: Open the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) while you are logged in in Facebook and use the ID which you get there.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your Facebook userID. Click on your facebook profile and your userID appears after facebook url, that is, https://www.facebook.com/yourUserID